# Any idea how can I pass Data from external site to Ploneformgen

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

while PHP can accept pass form data from external site.

Does plone / ploneformgen can do the same?

Can submit data by a url?

Comment: Submitting data by URL is akin to creating HTTP GET request against the form. There might be security implications on this, but there is nothing else besides security reasons which might prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'Overrides' tab of each field in order to pass in an arbitrary TALES
expression like

```
request/some_value|nothing
```

in order to provide a default based on data from the browser request (the 'some_value' parameter in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You may override the form submit "action". This will cause the form to bypass all server-side validity checking, though.

Alternatively, study some of the PloneFormGen add-ons which submit data to external services. These repost the data to the external service. That needs to be done in Python to manage the sanitation of data and deal with timeout problems with the external service.